# How can I strip all numbers from a string

Tags: vbscript

I would I go about stripping all numbers from a string?

This code below is what I have been trying.

```
objRegExp.Pattern = "((?![a-zA-Z]).)+"
queryForHTML = objRegExp.Replace(queryForHTML, "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KISS. You **want to find** all sequences of one or more digits (to delete them). So the pattern is "\d+". Trying to specify what you **don't** want to find/delete is errorprone/clumsy/not necessary.

```
>> Set re = New RegExp
>> re.Pattern = "\d+"
>> re.Global = True
>> WScript.Echo re.Replace("a1b234c", "")
>>
abc
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in JavaScript `/[0-9]/g` it will find all occurrences of digits, and your replace will trim those out. `/g` is for global, I think vbscript has a Global property which you can set